# using if statment to move and back up files

Tags: batch-file

```
for %%d in (text.txt, test1.txt)
    if c:\desktop\deploy_pkg\bin\%%d exist (
        del C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text.txt.bak
        del C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text1.txt.bak
        ren C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text.txt text.txt.bak
        ren C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text.txt text1.txt.bak
        copy "C:\Documents and Settings\deployment\Desktop\deploy_pkg\bin\text.txt" "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin"
        copy "C:\Documents and Settings\deployment\Desktop\deploy_pkg\bin\text1.txt" "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin"
     )
 )
pause
```

This is not working...any suggestions?

Comment: not working? how do you know? is it a syntax error? the result it no what you expected? does some smoke come out of your screen? ... put some effort in initial debugging and we will be happy to help you.

Comment: I have been debugging this all morning. I cannot get the batch file to successfully run. If you are not willing to help then leave your comments off my post. Thanks

Comment: Maybe re-read [some documentation of IF](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html)...

Comment: and take some attention to IF EXIST

Comment: Look I know nothing about creating a batch file. This my first time and I don't appriciate Mr. know-it-alls like you. I have done my reseach and just because I didn't post all my possible solutions doesn't mean I haven't tried to get this to work.

Comment: Relax -- this is not too hard to figure out by yourself. You have the order of the arguments wrong in the `if exist` command, like @PA. alluded to. Re-read the documentation carefully and compare it to your own code.

Comment: relax, and count your parentheses too.

Comment: @user1813261: to improve your question, describe what you expect the script to do, and what it's doing instead.  In particular, in this case it would be helpful to include the error message you get when you try to run it.

Answer (score 0):

## Answer

As mentioned in the comments to the original question, there are two syntax errors with your script.

1. The number of parentheses do not match. An open is needed for every close and vice versa.
2. The order of the `if` command is incorrect.  `exists` must come before the path.

Now these will only fix the script crashing issue and will not fix any errors that may exist in the logic of the script.  Without knowing the logic that the script is to perform it cannot be checked.

See `if /?` for help.

Also, Nate Hekman provided some good advice for writing questions on Stack Overflow.

### New to Batch

Here are some great resources for beginning with batch scripting.

[`SS64`](http://ss64.com/), [`Rob VanderWoulde`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchstart.php), [`DosTips`](http://www.dostips.com/), and [`Technet`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

### Syntax Fixes

```
for %%D in (text.txt, test1.txt) (
    if exist "c:\desktop\deploy_pkg\bin\%%~nxD" (
        del "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text.txt.bak"
        del "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text1.txt.bak"
        ren "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text.txt" "text.txt.bak"
        ren "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin\text.txt" "text1.txt.bak"
        copy "C:\Documents and Settings\deployment\Desktop\deploy_pkg\bin\text.txt" "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin"
        copy "C:\Documents and Settings\deployment\Desktop\deploy_pkg\bin\text1.txt" "C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\bin"
    )
)
pause
```